# In `dplyr/across` , how to exclude given columns

Tags: r, dplyr, across

In `dplyr/across`, i want to *-1 to numeric columns exclude `a1`  or excelue `a1` `a2`

```
library(tidyverse)    
raw_data <- data.frame(
  type=c('A','B','C'),
  cat=c("cat1","cat2","cat3"),
  a3=1:3,
  b2=1:3,
  c2=1:3,
  c1=1:3,
  a2=1:3,
  b1=1:3,
  a1=1:3)

#  * -1 to numeric columns exclude a1  
raw_data %>% mutate(across(where(is.numeric)&!='a1',~. *-1))

#  * -1 to numeric columns exclude a1 a2
raw_data %>% mutate(across(where(is.numeric)&!(. %in% c('a1','a2')),~. *-1))
```

Comment: Try `mutate(across(where(is.numeric) & !(c("a1", "a2")), ~ . * -1))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first argument in `across` is `.cols`, so just supply a vector of columns (`c()`) you want to in- or ex-clude.

```r
library(dplyr)

raw_data |> 
  mutate(across(c(where(is.numeric), -a1, -a2), ~ . * -1))

  type  cat a3 b2 c2 c1 a2 b1 a1
1    A cat1 -1 -1 -1 -1  1 -1  1
2    B cat2 -2 -2 -2 -2  2 -2  2
3    C cat3 -3 -3 -3 -3  3 -3  3
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try `!matches` like below

```
raw_data %>%
    mutate(across(!matches("a[12]") & where(is.numeric), ~ . * -1))
```

which gives

```
  type  cat a3 b2 c2 c1 a2 b1 a1
1    A cat1 -1 -1 -1 -1  1 -1  1
2    B cat2 -2 -2 -2 -2  2 -2  2
3    C cat3 -3 -3 -3 -3  3 -3  3
```